# Apply an ease function to a PathModifier?

Tags: android, andengine

In AndEngine I defined a PathModifier in this way

```
          public static IEaseFunction EASEFUNCTION;
                EASEFUNCTION =EaseSineInOut.getInstance();
                float[] coordinatesX = new float[300], coordinatesY = new float[300];
    for (int i=0; i<300; i++){
        coordinatesX[i] = i;
        coordinatesY[i] = (float)(20 * (Math.sin((-0.10 * coordinatesX[i]))));
        System.out.println(coordinatesX[i]);
        System.out.println(coordinatesY[i]);
    }
    PathModifier path = new PathModifier(10, coordinatesX, coordinatesY, EASEFUNCTION);
```

It's a mathematical function. I wanna to apply an EASEFunction to the PathModifier created by me. The constructor exists but none of the EASEFunctions don't works in this case. What's going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the `Path` object first, then pass it to the `PathModifier` constructor.

This will work:

```
Path path = new Path(coordinatesX, coordinatesY);
PathModifier modifier = new PathModifier(10, path, EaseSineInOut.getInstance());
```

I highly recommend you to download AndEngine's source code, so you can fix such small issues fast and with ease.

Comment: Is not working..I tried this , and others in a couple of ways but nothing. It seems that a custom path doesn't support EASE functions ?

Comment: Perhaps your version is old. The most updated version of GLES1 supports ease function with *all* modifier.

Comment: I downloaded the reccomended GLES1 1 week ago. At this point I suppose that the EASE functions could be applied only to Path.to(coordinates).to... statements as in the examples.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/entity/modifier/PathModifier.java?spec=svnffffe152e4c198bb857f94da85169d9119bb5a41&r=ffffe152e4c198bb857f94da85169d9119bb5a41 That's the latest version of `PathModifier`, and there are constructors accepting ease functions.